# Kernel failing to connect to the frontend

Tags: kernel, remote-access

I've been using Sakra's tunnel https://github.com/sakra to try to connect my mathematica in Linux to the server of my university.
The problem being that even though the SSH connection works well in the terminal, Mathematica seems to get

> The kernel ... failed to connect to the  front end. (Error =
> MLECONNECT) . You should try running the kernel connection outside the
> front end.

I've set it up so I don't need to insert the password in the terminal so that shouldn't be a problem.
Anyone knows what could cause this problem?